# VBA Copy a Row to another sheet if it matches a search

Tags: vba, excel

So currently I have a function that will search for two terms in a sheet and return True or False, depending whether it has found it or not. Now, what I'm trying to accomplish is, IF I find that entry, I want to copy the whole row where the entry was found at, to another sheet. I'm having some troubles going about it, and I'm not entirely sure how to proceed.

Here's my source code:

```
Private Function Search(BinStr As String, L4 As String) As Boolean
    Dim rng1 As Range
    Dim rng2 As Range

    Set rng1 = Worksheets("FirstSheet").Range("A:A").Find(BinStr, , xlValues, xlWhole)
    Set rng2 = Worksheets("FirstSheet").Range("C:C").Find(L4, , xlValues, xlWhole)
    If Not rng1 Is Nothing And Not rng2 Is Nothing Then
        rng1.Offset(0,1).Copy Destination:=Worksheets("Matches").Range("A")
        Search = True
    Else
        Search = False
    End If
End Function
```

Comment: Hi,its been a while for my VBA but does changing this line
rng1.Offset(0,1).Copy Destination:=Worksheets("Matches").Range("A")
to
rng1.Offset(0,1).EntireRow.Copy Destination:=Worksheets("Matches").Range("A")

help at all?

Comment: But this would have 2 rows it would find matches in... Would you want both copied? AND what if both matches occur in the same row?

Comment: Also, not essential as it is possible, but you USUALLY don't want a function to perform an action (such as copy rows) - It's usually used to return a value and then you use that value...

Comment: Functions in VBA can only modify the cell they are used in.

Comment: @JohnBustos yeah, it would be great if I could copy both rows.... but not sure how I should approach it.

Comment: Would it make sense to return the row it matches and have the macro copy the row/rows instead?

Answer (score 1):

Functions are meant to return values.  Based on the information you provided, you should really be using a subroutine that utilizes your custom search function.

```
Sub CopyMatches()
   If Search("string","other string") Then
      'code to copy row data to other worksheet
   End If
End Sub
```

Comment: The subroutine already looks like this, but the original subroutine doesn't actually know of anything of what's going in the search as it's searching in another sheet.

Comment: Edit your question with the code that uses the function.  Your answers will reflect how much detail you give us.